# InvalidCastException while instantiating PivotHeaderItem

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, drag-and-drop

I have a situation where I want to enable dropping functionality on the headers of a `Pivot` control in UWP.

One way that I could find is to override the template of the `PivotHeaderItem`, and add the events to handle dropping in a nested control.

While trying to find a better approach I tried to create a new `PivotHeaderItem` in my code-behind and assign it to the header property of the `PivotItem`, but I got this:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.__ComObject' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.IPivotHeaderItemFactory'.'
```

on this line:
`var pivotHeader = new PivotHeaderItem();`.

Comment: We can not initializes a new instance of the PivotHeaderItem control in code behind, you should be able to override the template of the `PivotHeaderItem`.

Comment: "We can not initializes a new instance of the PivotHeaderItem control in code behind" What do you mean by saying "We can not". As op states it throws exception, so it is designed to be like that ?